# Detect clipboard copy/paste event and modify clipboard contents

Tags: bash, scripts, clipboard, xclip, xsel

After something is copied to clipboard (using ctrl+c) I want a script (bash, python or any other language) to automatically detect that new entry is added to clipboard, change it's content and put it back to clipboard so when I paste it I get the modified text. The script should constantly run in background and monitor the clipboard for changes.

The following script describes the modification that is needed :
Source : https://superuser.com/questions/796292/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-copy-text-from-a-pdf-without-the-line-breaks

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# title: copy_without_linebreaks
# author: Glutanimate (github.com/glutanimate)
# license: MIT license

# Parses currently selected text and removes 
# newlines that aren't preceded by a full stop

SelectedText="$(xsel)"

ModifiedText="$(echo "$SelectedText" | \
    sed 's/\.$/.|/g' | sed 's/^\s*$/|/g' | tr '\n' ' ' | tr '|' '\n')"

#   - first sed command: replace end-of-line full stops with '|' delimiter and keep original periods.
#   - second sed command: replace empty lines with same delimiter (e.g.
#     to separate text headings from text)
#   - subsequent tr commands: remove existing newlines; replace delimiter with
#     newlines
# This is less than elegant but it works.

echo "$ModifiedText" | xsel -bi
```

**I do not want to use shortcut key binding to run the script.**

Comment: I checked the following questions : 1. [Automatically modify clipboard content (regex pattern replacement) when copy-pasting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873948/automatically-modify-clipboard-content-regex-pattern-replacement-when-copy-pas) but it is an Application Indicator 2. [Processing clipboard text through a script in between copy and paste](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399585/processing-clipboard-text-through-a-script-in-between-copy-and-paste) but it runs script manually.

Comment: Take a look at this:https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify  Run it like `while ./clipnotify; do echo "clipboard changed"; done`

Comment: Works very well. Should I write it as an answer ?

Comment: @kenn Do you know a clipnotify alternative for Wayland?

Answer (score 13):

Credit goes to [Kenn](https://askubuntu.com/users/81249/kenn).

I modified the script to my requirements and added the function to detect clipboard copy event and modify its contents.

[Source](https://github.com/SidMan2001/Scripts/tree/master/PDF-Copy-without-Linebreaks-Linux).

### Remove Line Breaks when copying text from PDF (Linux)

This bash script removes line breaks when copying text from PDF. It works for both Primary Selection and Clipboard of Linux.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# title: copy_without_linebreaks
# author: Glutanimate (github.com/glutanimate)
# modifier: Siddharth (github.com/SidMan2001)
# license: MIT license

# Parses currently selected text and removes 
# newlines

while ./clipnotify;
do
  SelectedText="$(xsel)"
  CopiedText="$(xsel -b)"
  if [[ $SelectedText != *"file:///"* ]]; then
    ModifiedTextPrimary="$(echo "$SelectedText" | tr -s '\n' ' ')"
    echo -n "$ModifiedTextPrimary" | xsel -i
  fi
  if [[ $CopiedText != *"file:///"* ]]; then
    ModifiedTextClipboard="$(echo "$CopiedText" | tr -s '\n' ' '  )"
    echo -n "$ModifiedTextClipboard" | xsel -bi
  fi
done
```

### Dependencies

1. **xsel**: `sudo apt install xsel`
2. [**clipnotify**](https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify). You can use the pre-compiled clipnotify provided in the repository or compile yourself.
   **To compile clipnotify yourself**

   ```
   sudo apt install git build-essential libx11-dev libxtst-dev
   git clone https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify.git
   cd clipnotify
   sudo make
   ```

### To USE

1. Download this repository as zip or copy and paste the script in a text editor and save it as copy_without_linebreaks.sh.
2. Make sure that script and clipnotify (downloaded or precompiled) are in the same folder.
3. Open terminal in script's folder and set permission
   `chmod +x "copy_without_linebreaks.sh"`
4. Double-click the script or run by entering in terminal :
   `.\copy_without_linebreaks.sh`
5. Copy text in pdf and paste it anywhere. Lines breaks will be removed.

Comment: Please click grey check mark next to your answer in two days time.

Comment: Does ```clipnotify``` support individual selection events? i.e. "primary", "secondary", "clipboard" or "buffer-cut". I commented a line in clipnotify.c to get events for only clipboard selection. i.e. https://i.imgur.com/FcY3REn.png

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not help for detecting paste events (if there's even such an event type). I want to update the clipboard when a value has been pasted, so one can easily paste a sequence of values one at a time.