# Can I register my own script to gnome accessibility menu?

Tags: gnome, scripts, menu, accessibility, top-bar

Let's say I'm on Ubtunu 20.04 and have a custom accessibility script that I can

- start by running `/opt/myTool/activate.sh`
- stop by running `/opt/myTool/deactivate.sh`.

Is there a way to register it to gnome accessibility menu in the top bar so it will appear as a toggle like the other tools such as "High Contrast", "Magnifier", "Screen Reader" etc?

[image]

Comment: This is possible by creating `gnome-shell-extension` but gnome-extensions are disabled once the screen gets locked and re-enabled once unlocked. Also extensions are re-run when `gnome-shell` refreshes or at every login. So your both the scripts may run multiple times in such situations.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4pi5.gif

Comment: @UnKNOWn yeah we better wait, but i expect he following steps to from https://askubuntu.com/q/1288732/26246 to make it easier.

Comment: @UnKNOWn The limitations of gnome-shell-extension you named are acceptable to me. user.dz guessed it correctly – it's the [script from the other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291516/1143661) I'm trying to make a toggle for. But I may have other applications as well. I'm looking forward to your answer! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the `gnome-shell-extension` CustomAccessibilityButton from this  [github-link](https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/LinkOnly)
2. To install the extension from the Downloaded zip file,
   change directory to the downloaded location. for Example if the Downloaded file is in `$HOME/Downloads`

   ```sh
   cd $HOME/Downloads
   gnome-extensions install CustomAccessibilityButton.zip
   ```
3. From the installed Extensions Directory run the `compile-schemas-script`

   ```
   cd $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/Custom\ Accessibility\ Button/
   ./compile-schemas-script
   ```
4. Refresh the gnome-shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> – "r" – <kbd>enter</kbd> method or logout/login
5. enable the extension

   ```
   gnome-extensions enable 'Custom Accessibility Button'
   ```
6. Refresh the gnome-shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> – "r" – <kbd>enter</kbd> method or logout/login

Now Custom Accessibility Button Should Appear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm! Could you explain what the file `schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.custom-button.gschema.xml` is for? I guess the items specified there will be rendered in some gsettings window or in the `gnome-extensions-app` but can't see anything.

Comment: You can see it in `dconf-editor` or `gsettings list-recursively | grep myscript`. When you toggle the button it gets signal and thus run the script based on the state `on|off`

Comment: @AntonS , GSettings is API of DConf which is the configuration back-end used by Gnome & Unity (may be some other GTK DE's). It was developed by Gnome project. `.gschema.xml` are settings declaration by app to register its settings in system `dconf` . You may interested to know more check https://askubuntu.com/q/416556/26246 or search for dconf/gsettings here. It is an advanced system that equivalent to Registry  in MS Windows, supports: default, system wide, user only, overrides, locks.

Comment: Unfortunately, Link is broken